# How to Store Text Data In App

Tags: android, local-storage

I am developing a **Quiz application**. I need to **store** the questions and answers(options) some where **in the app** so that I can fill the `TextView`'s `RadioButton`'s in a `Activity` Dynamically. How can I store such data and Access it to fill my `Activity`.

I am not sure about the concept. *Please suggest the best way to do this*.

Comment: Store files in an assets folder. It will be bundled in APK

Comment: @cricket_007 I Edited the question showing the real scenario where the problem is occurred, can you help me to find a solution. Still now I can't find a good solution. Some code samples will be very helpful.

Comment: Hi Ajay - Your question has been closed and the marked duplicate, therefore no more answers can be added. Adding an assets folder is probably the "best way" to store files in your app

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok. Then how can I get data from that asset file.

Comment: [Search: Android - Read from assets](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+read+from+assets)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank Very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use shared preferences to save local data, to check it in file folders manner you can use DDMS. You can also use SQLite.